# How to put condition in concatenation of columns

Tags: r

I wanted to concatenate two columns whereby one column is numeric and the other one is character specifically, quality sign (+/-). Below is example:

```
test <- data.frame(cbind(c(4,-5,6),c("-","-","-")),stringsAsFactors = F)
test$X1 <- paste0(test$X2,test$X1)
test$X1 <- as.numeric(test$X1)
```

[image: dataset:test]

As we can see the output is introduced by NAs due to coercion.

Can anyone please give a hint to solve this as to put condition during concatenation? Thanks.

Comment: The expected output is X1 <- -4 -5 -6

Comment: `ifelse(test$X1 < 0, test$X1,  paste0(test$X2,test$X1))`?

Comment: `test$X1 <- paste0(test$X2,abs(test$X1))`. Won't work in your example however since your numeric column is actually character.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen, so we have to set X1 as numeric first before concatenating them, am I right?

Comment: @JonSirNo Yes, you're using `cbind()` which returns a matrix, so all your columns become character and stay character when you convert it to a `data.frame`.

Comment: Yes absolutely @RonakShah. Btw, both ideas by kath and Humpelstielzchen work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem in your code is that for row 2 you get a string like this `--4` (note the **two** minus signs). So there are plenty of options as the comments showed you, yet another one would be

```
as.numeric(paste0(test$X2, 1)) * as.numeric(test$X1)
# [1] -4  5 -6
```